# Vue Wizard Form radio button validation

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working with vue-form-wizard by Cristi Jora integrating Element UI the basic example is here

```
    Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    formInline: {
      user: '',
      region: '',
      gender: ''
    },
    rules: {
      user: [{
        required: true,
        message: 'Please input Activity name',
        trigger: 'blur'
      }, {
        min: 3,
        max: 5,
        message: 'Length should be 3 to 5',
        trigger: 'blur'
      }],
      region: [{
        required: true,
        message: 'Please select Activity zone',
        trigger: 'change'
      }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onComplete: function() {
      alert('Yay. Done!');
    },
    validateFirstStep() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$refs.ruleForm.validate((valid) => {
          resolve(valid);
        });
      })

    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/409

but i am not able to validate radio buttons, please help me :(

here is my example
`https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/884/`

Comment: Looks like the validator only works with strings in order to validate `required`; the `el-radio-group` sets the `v-model` according to the radios' `:label`s, if you convert the labels to strings (`:label=" '9' "`) , the validator will work. https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/fjbL38en/ | I could look if there is any option in the validator, but `vue-form-wizard` doesn't specify which it uses.

Comment: Wow that is a good solution I really appreciate it, I never thought it. Thank you :)